# How do I make the recursion in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm creating a recursive function that returns me a list in Mem.
Cycle everything perfectly and then with the backtracking prolog returns the empty list.
Help.

```
Iniz([A1,A2|T], A1, Mem) :-
       append([],[], Mem),
       cicl([A2|T],A2, Mem).

cicl([],[], Mem) :- !.

cicl([A2],A2, Mem) :-
       string_chars(A2,A1_1),
       op(A1_1, Operation),!,
       append(Mem, [Operation], Lista),
       cicl([],[],Lista).

cicl([A1,A2|T],A1, Mem) :-
       string_chars(A1,A1_1),
       write("no operation"),
       nth0(0, A1_1, /),    
       nth0(1, A1_1, /),
       cicl([A2|T],A2, Mem).

cicl([A1,A2|T],A1, Mem) :-
      string_chars(A1,A1_1),
      nth0(0, A1_1, C), nth0(1, A1_1, C1),
      C \= /,
      C1 \= /,
      op(A1_1, Operation),!,
      append(Mem, [Operation], Lista),
      cicl([A2|T],A2, Lista).
```

Comment: How do you call this thing? Show an example of what you want and what you are actually getting. Right here: `cicl([],[], Mem) :- !.` what should `Mem` be if the first two arguments are `[]`? Your're currently indicated that you don't care what it is, so it is anonymous (shows up as `_Gxxxx`. Maybe that's so, but it's not clear.

Comment: cicl ([], [], Mem) I need to end the recursion.
In practice, once the file to be read is finished, this is the last function that should come in when the list is empty and should print the memory.

Comment: Yes, I know it's the end of the recursion. But you have a singleton variable, `Mem`. Do you care what it is at the end of recursion? Also, again, please show how you call your predicate, show what results you get, and show what results you expect/want.

Comment: First, `Iniz` is not a valid predicate name because it begins with a capital letter. Second, `append([],[],Mem)` is an overcomplex way of saying `Mem=[]`, and this is forcing `cicl([A2|T],A2,Mem)` to fail to unify. You need a fourth variable for the return path of `Mem`, because you're fixing the value on the way in.

Comment: Also, I think `C \= /,` is a parse error, so you may have missed something there.